# Push notification server settings for iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I have developed a push notification module and made all the settings required.

In the configuration section of the module it says, The filename for the development certificate should be `apns-development-fdd6bfba49.pem`, the production certificate should be `apns-production-fdd6bfba49.pem`.

If I generate the certificate with same name only then it works. If i upload .pem file with any other name like `apns-production.pem` for production certificate it gives this error:-

> Failed to enable crypto in push_notifications_open_apns(). 
>   APNS connection could not be established. Check to make sure you are using a valid certificate file.

I am very sure it is not command execution problem. Kindly help as to why am I getting  this error.

What should I do? Please reply if anyone has an answer for this. I am struggling to get the production certificate.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this tutorial link carefully this link contains all steps for push notification

https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://gist.github.com/f01cdf4369c86ddd6d71&ei=T7qBAHlP&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=562&ts=1445967447&sig=APONPFnG7ZC6unanAkdMPEokkq_SLhPkjA

Just be careful while creating ck.pem file.

Comment: I referred the same tutorial. The certificate is correctly generated and I am also getting the notification provided the name of the ck.pem file is apns-production-fdd6bfba49.pem. But if the .pem file name is something else say abc.pem, it doesn't work. I checked the server configuration and it says.. The filename for the development certificate should be apns-development-fdd6bfba49.pem, the production certificate should be apns-production-fdd6bfba49.pem...

Comment: Hi smita,Why you are changing the name of .pem file ? Give the name of .pem file whatever you want when you create a pem file.